# sphinx how to Include inheritance diagrams

Tags: python-2.7, python-sphinx

I am trying to generate the doc of a package using python-sphinx.
I am having hard time to create the so called classes 'inheritance diagrams'
I am still a novice in sphinx but this is what I am doing to generate my doc.

```
# in the windows command line
C:\Python27_32bit\Scripts\sphinx-apidoc.exe -o .\source .\
C:\Python27_32bit\Scripts\sphinx-build.exe -b html .\source .\build
```

execcuting those two lines will generate automatically my doc. sphinx-apidoc creates the indexes files and sphinx-build will build my html doc

Any idea how to add an inheritance diagrams of all the package classes ?

Comment: sphinx-apidoc outputs .rst source files with `automodule` directives to simplify generation of API documentation. It does not add any [`inheritance-diagram`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/inheritance.html#directive-inheritance-diagram) directives automatically. You'll have to add these directives yourself at suitable places in the documentation sources.