# How to add inheritance diagram to all modules in Sphinx?

Tags: graph, python-sphinx, diagram, docstring, read-the-docs

So I've been trying to get Sphinx to generate inheritance diagrams for all submodules / classes when generating `.rst` files through `sphinx-apidoc`, similar to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911669/sphinx-how-to-include-inheritance-diagrams). But I have not found any built-in features to do this in Sphinx.

The nearest solution I found was to [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911669/sphinx-how-to-include-inheritance-diagrams) add an inheritance diagram line with the class name to each class docstring in code, but this is not very convenient.

So the question is how do I add inheritance diagrams to all module 
`.rst` files?

Comment: If you have a question and its solution, it is fine to post both. But don't include the solution in the question. First post the question, then the answer. That is how Stack Overflow works (welcome, by the way!).

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250204/407651

Comment: Yeah first post, thanks for the input :) Will do that next time!

Comment: Don't wait until next time. You should remove the "answer part" of this question and put it in a proper answer.

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution to the problem:

1. Go to the folder `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sphinx/templates/apidoc/`
2. Open `package.rst_t`
3. After `*{{- [submodule, "module"] | join(" ") | e | heading(2) }}*` add:

   ```
   .. inheritance-diagram:: {{submodule}}

      :parts: 1
   ```

You also need to add these extentions in the `conf.py` file when making the html files:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.graphviz','sphinx.ext.inheritance_diagram']
```

To make the graphs more readable I also added this to `conf.py` (TB=Top to bottom view):

```
inheritance_graph_attrs = dict(rankdir="TB", size='""')
```